# Algorithm for solving simultaneous nonlinear noninvertible equations

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, systems-of-equations, numerical-optimization

I am looking for an algorithm (numerical or otherwise) which can solve simultaneous equations if those equations are nonlinear and noninvertible.

For example, for the set of equations

$Z_1 = \frac{x}{x+y} e^{xy} + \frac{x+1}{y}$

$Z_2 = y e^{x+y} + \frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+y-1)}$,

I have measured values ($Z_1$, $Z_2$). For each set ($Z_1$, $Z_2$), I would like to know which ($x$, $y$) ordered pair(s) will satisfy the two functions given my measured ($Z_1$, $Z_2$).

I have solved the problem by brute force numerical crunching but I am sure there must be a better method since this is a common problem in physics and geometry.

For a description of the functions and the experimentally measured data points, I have posted the actual problem in a python jupyter notebook here:
https://github.com/enlightenedscience/Viscoelastic_modeling_for_QCM/blob/master/voinova_numerical_solver_single_step.ipynb

Comment: if you can get a close enough guess, there is a version of Newton's method that uses the inverse of the Jacobian matrix, so one may rapidly improve things. http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Spring17/Multidimensional-Newton.pdf

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the meaning of the word "noninvertible" in this context. Do you mean to say that the exists points where the Jacobian is singular?

Comment: By noninvertible, I mean that the form of the equations prevents me from rearranging them to represent x as a function of y, or y as a function of x.

Comment: http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/pbe/publications/Newton.pdf